# matplotlib only shows the last imshow()ed picture

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skGyc.png)I am trying to implement gamma law here. I need to run that array and print 5 separate images for each gamma value, but I ma only getting the output for gamma = 2.2. Rest images I am not getting, however the for loop is running for all the gamma values provided in the array. Can someone plz help me out regarding this. Your help will be appreciated. I am coding in Python in Google Colab. Thank you!!

Here is the Question and the code

Question-
Apply the formula  255∗(image/255)gamma
gamma values are given below

convert the array to 'uint8' datatype and plot the image for each and every gamma value.

```
gamma = [0.1, 0.5, 1.2, 1.8, 2.2]
```

CODE HERE

```
import cv2
for i in gamma:
    cub5 = np.array(255*(cub/255)**i,dtype='uint8')
    plt.imshow(cub5)
```

Comment: just add `plt.figure()` before you use `plt.imshow` in each iteration. Or use `plt.subplots()` check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

> Note: I am using `matplotlib` to read the image, instead of the `cv2` that you are using. So feel free to replace that part.

#### Approach 1: Creating new figures in each iteration

You have to create a new `plt.figure()` during each loop. Try adding this as below -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

gamma = [0.1, 0.5, 1.2, 1.8, 2.2]

cub = plt.imread('cub.png')

for i in gamma:
    plt.figure()      #<--------------------
    cub5 = np.array(255*(cub/255)**i,dtype='uint8')
    plt.imshow(cub5)
```

#### Approach 2: Using subplots

However, I would recommend a better way to do this would be to create subplots. Check the code below for the general approach.

> You didn't post the cub image so I found a kitten instead, close enough I think!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

gamma = [0.1, 0.5, 1.2, 1.8, 2.2]

cub = plt.imread('cat1.png')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,2, figsize=(10,10))

for g,ax in zip(gamma,axes.ravel()):
    cub5 = np.array(255*(cub/255)**g,dtype='uint8')
    ax.imshow(cub5)
    ax.set_title('gamma:'+str(g))
    
fig.delaxes(axes[2,1]) #delete unused axes
```

[image]